# Multi-Device-Hybrid-Apps cannot build for android target import org.apache.cordova.*; error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

---Update---

Did a repair on the vs2013mda_0.1.1.exe and updated in sdk manager 
This was suggested in a previous question and I updated before posting and just updated again.

SDK Tools 22.6.4
SDK Platform-Tools 19.0.2
SDK Build Tools 19.1

There most be something wrong with cordovalib not being found.

I can build in eclipse, but it will not run in emulator.

Just want to get this working in visual studio

---original post---

Evaluating Multi-Device-Hybrid-Apps - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381

clean win81 machine with vs2013 up2 and Multi-Device-Hybrid-Apps installed.  Create new Multi-Device-Hybrid-Apps project and build succeeds for ripple.

Try to build for android emulator and receive 2 errors:
Seems to be caused by import org.apache.cordova.*; failing.

Called microsoft and they never heard of this feature, they asked me to post on SO

```
Error   2   c:\bin\vs13\cordova\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2    c:\bin\vs13\cordova\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\EXEC  1   1   BlankCordovaApp1
Error   3   The command ""C:\Users\jayl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Android" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaApp1" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "AndroidEmulator"" exited with code 8. C:\Users\jayl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets 68  5   BlankCordovaApp1
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

This appears to be a bug in the way the Android project is built when its base directory is "bin". The solution is to rename that directory to something else (e.g. "projects"). The build should then proceed without error.

<s>This is a known issue due to an Android library being renamed recently.</s>
<s>Open up the SDK manager and install the latest android build tools and this error should go away.</s>

Comment: I have already done this, there are other stackoverflow questions with this answer.

Comment: See update for details SDK Tools 22.6.4 SDK Platform-Tools 19.0.2 SDK Build Tools 19.1 - this is a clean machine how can the install not work ???

Comment: Just wondering, did you create a AVD before trying to deploy to the emulator?

Comment: yes, and it is running it is the build process that is failing

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine? Seeing as how things are running on Ripple, it's odd that this is failing for the emulator.

Comment: I have not tried to run on the emulator from visual studio only tried to build.

Comment: build from the command line fails as well in the platforms\android\cordova folder I run build.bat and get the same errors.

Comment: I tried rebooting and still getting the errors.

There was a similar issue with phonegap

Originally there was a cordova.jar file they changed to using the cordovalib project that would be imported into eclipse.


It seems like the same issue.

The import line is what is failing, 

error: package org.apache.cordova does not exist
1>      [javac] import org.apache.cordova.*;

Comment: I've updated the solution with the fix. Seems like you were using a reserved keyword as your base folder name.

Comment: Bingo.  I do not understand but thanks for solving this issue.  I have created many android projects with phonegap and cordova under this bin folder.  Maybe you can explain.

Comment: @JLeiser The only explanation I can think of is that this is a bug in more recent Cordova versions. I just tried recreating the issue without installing the MDHA package (i.e. just installing node.js, ant, Cordova, Java, and the Android SDK) and I see the same issue with having "bin" as the base directory.